# Get an adbExec error after trying to create session in Appium Inspector

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am a newbie in the Appium, and I get such error while trying to start a session through the Appium Inspector:

```
Failed to create a session. 
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: Error executing adbExec.
 Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\xukin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -g C:\\Windows\\system32\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\apks\\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; 
Command output: 
adb: failed to stat C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk: No such file or directory
```

Capabilities:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:platformVersion": "12",
  "appium:deviceName": "Pixel XL",
  "appium:app": "C:/Users/xukin/OneDrive/Документы/app-release.apk",
  "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
  "appium:udid": "emulator-5554"
}
```

I looked at this path, and the file was there. Someone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like `Settings` app that's needed by `appium` is missing. Can you check if this file exists? `C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk`

Comment: @HemChe Yes, that's it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJ392MSqGGokSK7ght_g8IJI3ncEHZUu/view?usp=sharing